# Is GLSurfaceView necessary for drawing a plot?

Tags: java, android, drawing, glsurfaceview

I'm developing an app that will connect to (my own) oscilloscope, read data via USB and display plots - so just normal oscilloscope.

USB is ok, now I have to draw the graphs.

As you know (or not) in oscilloscope there are really fast-changing signals, so I have to render graphs really fast.
So I'm looking for a fast way to do it.

I've read that GLSurfaceView uses OpenGL and GPU so it is used for games, but **will I benefit from it in my project?** 
GL is really complicated (to draw a square or just lines, not to mention about text...) while SurfaceView has its Canvas so it's much easier.

I really care for performance, but have not much time and nerver used OpenGL so what do you think?

Answer (score 0):

It *is* complicated, but you *will* benefit from GLES when using a SurfaceView.

Canvas on SurfaceView is not hardware-accelerated, so on some devices you'll have trouble hitting 60fps.  (See for example the "multi-surface test" in [Grafika](https://github.com/google/grafika).  Tap the "bounce" button to cause it to animate.  On some devices it'll do 60fps, on others it won't hit 30fps.)

One alternative would be to create a custom View.  That way the rendering would be accelerated by hardware.